# vb.net variables calculating incorrect value

Tags: vb.net

i am running this code in vb.net:

```
Dim sub_total as Double = 0

Dim amount As Double = 0
Dim customer_total As Double = 0

SQL = "SELECT invoice, product, cost, price, commission FROM billing_salesman_commission WHERE invoice = '" & reader2.GetString(0) & "';"
myCommand3.Connection = conn3
myCommand3.CommandText = SQL
reader3 = myCommand3.ExecuteReader
While reader3.Read
    'profit = sell price - cost price
     amount = reader3.GetString(3) - reader3.GetString(2)

     'commission amount = profit * (commission % / 100)
     amount = amount * (reader3.GetString(4) / 100)

     'update the customer total
     customer_total = customer_total + amount

     'insert excel data
     'MsgBox("insert excel")
End While
reader3.Close()

sub_total = sub_total + customer_total
```

from the query above that creates a loop, i have calculated all of the figures manually on a calculator.

there are 2 unique values for `invoice` and each one totals the following:

- 5.44
- 9.41

which should equal `14.85` however sub_total is returning `14.84`

Comment: `amount = reader3.GetString(3) - reader3.GetString(2)` is subtracting strings and assigning the result to a double.  Please turn on Option Strict.

Comment: what should they be other than strings? or could i wrap val() around both of them ?

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, what are the actual runtime values when it fails?

Comment: it doesnt fail, its processing through the code fine but its just creating the wrong value

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem without the db?  Eg. use hard coded text strings rather than reader3.GetString(3).  Also this seems to me to be a rounding error.

Comment: I would not recommend using doubles to store currency values.  Doubles are more for abstract scientific numbers.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net.  I would recommend using a decimal type - it _may_ be more accurate.

Comment: @charlie uses the decimal data type that is 10 times more accurate

Comment: ive changed `Double` to `Decimal` and its now producing all 0 values

Comment: Not for nothing but rather than using `String` like it is programming duct tape, the reader can fetch back typed values:  `amount = amount * reader3.GetDecimal(4)`  or Double as the case may be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were trying to subtract strings. For code string is a bunch of letters and signs and digits within string are treated as letters.

```
amount = reader3.GetString(3) - reader3.GetString(2)
```

You can fix this few different ways:

```
amount = (Convert.ToDecimal(reader3.GetString(3)))-(Convert.ToDecimal(reader3.GetString(2))


amount = CDec(reader3.GetString(3)) - CDec(reader3.GetString(2))
```

best way as it will prevent exception:

**UPDATE:**

Change these:

```
Dim sub_total as Double = 0
Dim amount As Double = 0
Dim customer_total As Double = 0
```

to:

```
Dim sub_total, amount, customer_total As Decimal
```

then this should work:

```
Dim costDec, sellDec, profit, commission as Decimal
If (Decimal.TryParse(reader3.GetString(3), costDec) AND Decimal.TryParse(reader3.GetString(2), sellDec) AND Decimal.TryParse(reader3.GetString(2), commission)) Then
    amount = costDec - sellDec
    profit = amount * (commission/100)
    customer_total = customer_total + profit
End If
```

Just a comment to above logic, your naming convention is weird as it suggests that you want to calculate total cost for customer when you are only calculating commission of profits.

Comment: ive checked some other code, which is this `cdr_client_total + Val(reader4.GetString(1)) / 100` and thats working fine - its stored in my DB as `Decimal 10,2`

Comment: I'm not sure In understand, so your code works now? Val will work but it was made for different scenarios. IsNumeric() will also work

Comment: its not working - thats a different function i have in my application

Answer (score 1):

'change your code:

```
 Option strict on

 Dim sub_total as decimal= 0
 Dim amount As decimal= 0
 Dim customer_total As decimal= 0

   SQL = "SELECT invoice, product, cost, price, commission FROM billing_salesman_commission WHERE invoice = '" & reader2.GetString(0) & "';"

  myCommand3.Connection = conn3
  myCommand3.CommandText = SQL
  reader3 = myCommand3.ExecuteReader
     While reader3.Read

 'profit = sell price - cost price
 amount = cdec(reader3.GetString(3)) - cdec(reader3.GetString(2))

 'commission amount = profit * (commission % / 100)
 amount = amount * cdec(reader3.GetString(4) / 100)

 'update the customer total
 customer_total = cdec(customer_total) + cdec(amount)

 'insert excel data
 'MsgBox("insert excel")
 End While
 reader3.Close()

  sub_total = sub_total + customer_total
```

Comment: ive checked some other code, which is this cdr_client_total + Val(reader4.GetString(1)) / 100 and thats working fine - its stored in my DB as Decimal 10,2